# Python HTML getElementsByClassName alike manipulate on file content

Tags: javascript, python, dom, tags, html-parsing

I have saved the source code of a page to a file using Sikuli. I need a "roundup" on a batch of matrix style placed elements. But I don't want to calculate dimensions between them. I want URLs to type in location bar. So I wrote from scratch with a help of MZDN JavaScript implementation of such a "simple" operation. I don't want to use lxml. I want real native libraries - I mean I need "portable" script.
So I've googled a while and decided to ask a question at Stack OverFlow.
I don't want to use

```
split('<a href=')
```

magic.
I would like to do this in Python(in the most pythonic way):

```
var array = document.getElementsByClassName('another')

var j = array.length
for (i=0;i<j;i++) {
    element = array[i];
    url = element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
    console.log(url);
    }

var array = document.getElementsByClassName('else')
var j = array.length
for (i=0;i<j;i++) {
    element = array[i];
    url = element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
    console.log(url);
    }
```

Managed to do it with `split`. Python is for kids.

```
def read_file(filename):
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    data = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    return data

def href(line):
        url = line.split('a href=')[1].split('>')[0].strip().replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
        return url

html = read_file('source.htm').split('\n')
for line in html:
    if 'one' in line:
        print href(line)
    elif 'another' in line:
        print href(line)
    elif 'else' in line:
        print href(line)
```

Comment: do you want to translate this code to Python?

Comment: Yes! I want this to be done in *.py file which is a part of *.sikuli.

Comment: I'm growing. So I understand that Python is not so good for everything. I made this easily with JavaScript but making it pythonic will eat again a day of my time. So I'd rather to listen to clever people.

Comment: I could help you but only using external libraries, I dont know anybody who parses html using native ones, unfortunately they are not so good.

Comment: Thanks for help. BeautifulSoup might probably help. I could place its folder near the script. But it doesn't findAll when classnames contain spaces. And I don't want to use functions which I learned there to make this module adecvate. jshell (from Mozilla) doesn't know getElementsByClassName so avoid.

Comment: Yep Python is really easy! If you still want something more pythonic paste a snippet of your html somewhere(in order to test) and I will write it for you.